# Sharepoint Wiki through an Apache Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, sharepoint-2007

I have set up a reverse proxy in Apache for the purpose of redirecting traffic to my internal sharepoint server, amongst other things.  The problem I am running into is, if I create a reference to a yet uncreated wiki page [[testLink]] then click the link, it returns a hard address to the internal server name, and thus, when outside the local network, doesn't work.

Is there any way to fix this?  I am baffled, I don't even know where to start looking for logs on this matter.

Any help would be appreciated :)  Thanks!

Edit:  I should note I suppose that this is the only part that doesn't seem to work correctly.

Edit2:  Here is the code for the virtualhost;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sharepoint.mydomain.com 
ProxyPass / http://sharepointserver.mydomain.com/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://sharepointserver.mydomain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys for your input.  Unfortunately,  I think something was lost in translation.  I have mod_proxy_html working (otherwise the other 99% of this sharepoint site wouldn't work).  The problem is solely on a new page generated automatically in the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the redirects.  If you are using ProxyPass modify your apache configuration to also use ProxyPassReverse.

ProxyPassReverse /app1/ http://internal1.example.com/

You can find more information at http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/reverse-proxy-apache.html

Comment: Sorry about all the edits!  I'm learning how to do codeblocks and such :)  Check my post again.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) might do what you need.